# Configuring mobile home directories on Yosemite OS X Server

Tags: macos, osx-server, profile-manager

I have Open Directory configured on a brand new OS X machine with Server.app set up on it. I'm trying to configure the mobile account setup on the server, to allow users to sync their home directories up to the server volume (for backup / recovery purposes). I cannot seem to get this to behave correctly, and the documentation from Apple on this is thin at-best.

My objective is to have users login to their laptops using their Open Directory account, and have the computer create a "mobile account" on the local machine that can be kept in sync with the server. I can get an account to login successfully using the OD account, but it seems to ignore the settings I have configured within Profile Manager (the "policies" for the users).

Does anyone know how to get this working? Is there a good resource for how to set up?

Comment: On the client end, in one of the OD users logged into a client Mac, have you verified the Mobile Account settings in System Preferences > Users & Groups > User Account > Mobile account?

Comment: When I got into that preference pane, I can see a "Create Mobile Account" option. When I do this it forces me to sign out/in, then after that that section of the pref pane is greyed out. I also don't see any server-side mobile profile for that user account anywhere...

Comment: Is the client enrolled for profile management? Note that this is separate from binding to OD.